How can I scrape the links to the patents from Espacenet using Python?
I need to scrape links to the patents from my search result on Espacenet.
Since Espacenet is a dynamic website, simple way with Beautiful Soup and Requests doesn't work.
I tried to use Selenium together with Beautiful Soup, but this didn't work.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://worldwide.espacenet.com/patent/search?q=%28pa%20all%20%22imperial%22%20AND%20pa%20all%20%22innovations%22%29%20AND%20pd%20within%20%222014%22'

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get(url)             

soup = BeautifulSoup(       
    driver.page_source,
    'html.parser'
)

urls = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))

The output gives me only one link (instead of 103 expected) and this link is not a patent link. Here is it. Probably the links to patents are hidden somehow and don't get found using 'a' tag.
I also tried this approach, described here, however it wasn't helpful either.
import requests
main_url="https://worldwide.espacenet.com/patent/search?q=%28pa%20all%20%22imperial%22%20AND%20pa%20all%20%22innovations%22%29%20AND%20pd%20within%20%222014%22"

res=requests.get("https://worldwide.espacenet.com/patent/search?q=%28pa%20all%20%22imperial%22%20AND%20pa%20all%20%22innovations%22%29%20AND%20pd%20within%20%222014%22")
main_data=res.json()
data=main_data['results']['cluster']

for i in range(len(data[0]['result'])): 
    num=data[0]['result'][i]['patent']['publication_number']
    print(num)
    print(main_url+"patent/"+num+"/en"+params)


It gave me JSONDecoder Error:

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Is it even possible to scrape these links?
I need to get a df or a dictionary with Patent title and corresponding link. For example:
like this

Please update your question to provide an example of the data/output you are hoping to get from scraping this page. This will make it easier for us to troubleshoot ways of getting the data you are after.

is there an error message? have you checked if there is something at all in your result?

First of all your target app is protected by Cloudflare and you have to use all the necessary headers, and cookies to resolve the 403 Forbidden error. After analyzing the request I found out that Cookie, User-Agent, Referer, and Epo-Trace-Id: wie4us-etqwuf-AAA-000001 is mandatory to prove you are a human to Cloudflare so don't forget to add your cookie and user-agent in the script. (I included my cookies and user-agent header in the script)
I used this https://worldwide.espacenet.com/3.2/rest-services/search?lang=en%2Cde%2Cfrq={query} API endpoint in my script to load all the 103 results, here is the code:
import requests
from urllib.parse import quote
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning) #disable urllib HTTP warning

headers = {
    'Cookie': '__cf_bm=1_YwWsJT2LrzpGQ1DHVcB06fQKbJk3ZpZRT_GRZVDvY-1728909016-1.0.1.1-PaoOD9MzAIc9pwsgeUJoMzTcmfEr9I8wqQiF4cIuRoLu79v4tY5FIzI0KncO71jEx48cgWOUUVPXLznqYzNCew; _cfuvid=iSuLFpm4o2QijuDGvZWS.0lYYQJ5FfOYsQNf.JCDWrg-1728909017605-0.0.1.1-604800000; cf_chl_rc_m=1; cf_clearance=aQbYNLPcghnkgkGiajNDA4LOvbqsgJ5Yo0B9qzi5n7Q-1728909103-1.2.1.1-LF.LzgQxDh8c53fe4AzGnYEp7kbLV8QDs6y5H.7tXuWM.v6XzJo5Op8GXAJE2.4IBgAfGC_BbmOIZrG57udQsBUaN3RGuiHGDk3RmB19bFq6AMZp5ooi00relCmJSZvxoz2CbgDhe1csvTrwwANQYZVgDwivvCDWR0Rsz168mLCWgFe3DEShZsTjCqnNSvW8hOsxSaZjM_yFg_2o1PFh7qc0JCKNnLvrYE7msKJDh3rzW6FZNr54FVkRVtQLiJJEOe5oUaK3UtDWdHpZeb9K_onFGKlhXnm3ktGHKGMP8gS58nq_OI1AqOafZxF4stGXa05JRJ7sgmQwxrOwl3RBf2WggkPSLz98Kq890cKCKBUjep9OaxGtzP497UfIJn6UO3vnoIeX_MerVMnaSkIB_A',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:130.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/130.0',
    'Epo-Trace-Id': 'wie4us-etqwuf-AAA-000001',
    'Referer': 'https://worldwide.espacenet.com/patent/search?q=%28pa%20all%20%22imperial%22%20AND%20pa%20all%20%22innovations%22%29%20AND%20pd%20within%20%222014%22'
}

def sendRequest(query):
    q = quote(query, safe='')
    data = {"query":{"fields":["publications.ti_*","publications.abs_*","publications.pn_docdb","publications.pd","publications.in_patents","publications.inc_patents","publications.pa_patents","publications.pac_patents","publications.pr_docdb","publications.app_fdate.untouched","oprid_full.untouched","opubd_full.untouched","publications.ipc_ic","publications.ipc_icci","publications.ipc_iccn","publications.ipc_icai","publications.ipc_ican","publications.ci_cpci","publications.ca_cpci","publications.cl_cpci","biblio:pa;in;in_patents;pa_patents;inc_patents;pac_patents;in_orig_patents;pa_orig_patents;in_unstd_patents;pa_unstd_patents;pd;pn_docdb;allKindCodes;"],"from":0,"size":200,"highlighting":[{"field":"publications.ti_en","fragment_words_number":20,"number_of_fragments":3,"hits_only":True},{"field":"publications.abs_en","fragment_words_number":20,"number_of_fragments":3,"hits_only":True},{"field":"publications.ti_de","fragment_words_number":20,"number_of_fragments":3,"hits_only":True},{"field":"publications.abs_de","fragment_words_number":20,"number_of_fragments":3,"hits_only":True},{"field":"publications.ti_fr","fragment_words_number":20,"number_of_fragments":3,"hits_only":True},{"field":"publications.abs_fr","fragment_words_number":20,"number_of_fragments":3,"hits_only":True},{"field":"publications.pn_docdb","fragment_words_number":20,"number_of_fragments":3,"hits_only":True},{"field":"publications.pa_patents","fragment_words_number":20,"number_of_fragments":3,"hits_only":True}]},"filters":{"publications.patent":[{"value":["true"]}]},"widgets":{}}
    url = f"https://worldwide.espacenet.com/3.2/rest-services/search?lang=en%2Cde%2Cfr&q={q}&qlang=cql&"
    resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data, verify=False)
    main_data = resp.json()['hits']
    for n, i in enumerate(main_data):
        try:
            pub_num = i['hits'][0]['fields']['publications.pn_docdb'][0]
            pub_name = i['hits'][0]['fields']['publications.ti_en'][0]
            family_num = i['familyNumber']
            pub_url = f"https://worldwide.espacenet.com/patent/search/family/{family_num}/publication/{pub_num}?q={q}"
            print(f"================\nPublication No: {n+1}\nPublication Title:  {pub_name}\nPublication URL: {pub_url}")
        except Exception:
            pass

sendRequest('(pa all "imperial" AND pa all "innovations") AND pd within "2014"') # your query which fetches the data

Let me know if this works on your end!

Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.
I get this error:
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
do you know what might be the reason behind it?
could you please also tell me how you checked cookie for this website?

this was my cookie with the user-agent so it will work only on my end, I told you to use your own, here is how - Firefox = visit the site --> right click inspect --> go to network tab --> click one of the requests from your target site --> scroll down and copy the Cookie: value from the request header. same for Chrome, don't forget to add your own browser's user-agent header value.

this worked! Thank you so much!
